# Inconsistent gap between inline-block elements when using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

When using Bootstrap "btn"-styled inline-block elements, I'm getting an inconsistent (sometimes 3px, sometimes 4px) gap between them (viewing in Chrome).

I'm aware that inline-block elements will have a gap whenever there's whitespace between them, but I've never encountered gaps of varying sizes before. It makes it impossible to apply traditional fixes like setting a -4px negative margin.

Why is this happening?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="h-wrap">
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
<a class="btn btn-default">Some</a>
</div>
<div class="h-wrap">
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.h-wrap > * {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EXAMPLES:**
http://jsfiddle.net/0tophozu/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/0tophozu/5/

---

**NOTE:** I'm not looking for alternative white space solutions- I just want to understand why the gap is inconsistent.

Comment: Long story short: a space is not exactly 4px wide. The inline blocks will align with pixels after rounding.

Comment: @SalmanA - thanks for that link- wasn't finding anything myself

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, it is an odd problem that popped up only recently.